# Question about the Hessian Criterion on a curve with singularity

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

So in class we have this theorem we call the Hessian Criterion:
If we have a singular point in an affine curve in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Then

$\frac{ \partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}\frac{ \partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2} \not= \big(\frac{ \partial ^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \big)^2$

If and only if (a,b) is an ordinary double point.

My question is understanding / proving this.
(Assume ordinary double point)
 I mean I see that we can taylor expand the polynomial f into $f =f(a,b) + \frac{ \partial f(a,b)}{\partial x}(x-a)+ \frac{ \partial  f(a,b) }{\partial y}(y-b) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{ \partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x-a)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{ \partial ^2 f}{\partial y^2} (y-b)^2+\frac{ \partial ^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}(x-a)(y-b)+ \text{stuff}$

Where by (a,b) singular the f(a,b) and the first derivatives are zero. Then I think that having a ordinary double point means that the polynomial defined by $\frac{1}{2}\frac{ \partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x-a)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{ \partial ^2 f}{\partial y^2} (y-b)^2+\frac{ \partial ^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}(x-a)(y-b)$ does not equal zero and factors into distinct roots. I think I can use a hand understanding what is happening.

Thank you

Comment: Dear Gidy, complete squares in your quadratic term and for convenience, write $x-a=z_1$ and $x-b=z_2$. If the determinant is different from zero, you have something like $y_1y_2=0$, that is, two transversal lines. If the determinant is zero, you have $y_1^2=0$, that is, only one line.